# Piece in Lego 21327 Typewriter Step 26 can’t be flush as depicted in the illustration

Tags: technic, building, instructions

When sliding part #6327028 down the left three rods as depicted in step 26, that piece becomes snug with the gray spacer piece from Step 25, but there’s a gap on the two left rods. The 1x5 black spacer (part #6327028) can’t remain level if brought to be snug with the black spacer piece, as depicted in Step 27. I’ve rebuilt the mechanism from the beginning with the same results. Either Lego forgot to have us add a spacer, or the illustration is wrong.

I’ve made the 1x5 black spacer (part #6327028) level from the gray spacer, but I’m wondering if the arm on the rod second from the left will be all right floating there. I can’t find anyone complaining about this issue online, but I do see complaints about the mechanism jamming, and here I am finding a problem with the mechanism.

If I threw in a gray spacer piece on the second rod from the left, that would ensure the arm is fastened snugly in place, but that 1x5 black spacer would still be off by half a brick according to the illustration. Suggestions?

(Thanks RSchulz for the assist!)

[image: steps 25 and 26]

[image: steps 27 and 28]

[image: Depiction of the gap]

[image: Shot from the back]

Comment: Can you add another picture of the opposite side of your assembly?

Comment: Below your half bush (what you call a "gray spacer") there should be a liftarm 1x3 half thickness in dark bluish gray (both added in step 25). However from your picture, there seems to be a black element there instead, likely of full thickness

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve Your comment seems like an answer to me :)

Comment: @zovits, done...

Answer (score 9):

Below your [half bush](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4265c#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) (what you call a "gray spacer") there should be a [liftarm 1x3 half thickness](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6632&name=Technic,%20Liftarm%20Thin%201%20x%203%20-%20Axle%20Holes&category=%5BTechnic,%20Liftarm%5D#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:%2285%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) in dark bluish gray (both added in step 25). However from your picture, there seems to be a black element there instead, likely of full thickness. Any chance you put a black [1x3 full thickness liftarm](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32523#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) there instead?

Comment: Thank you! That’s exactly what went wrong. I became sick after making this original post, so I’m only now able to reply. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sickbrick don't be so hard to yourself. We've all made mistakes in the past. On a positive side - thing this is an easy fix!

Comment: Thank you very much for your careful, detailed answer. I am embarrassed to say I had done the same mistake! Thank you for not telling us to take everything apart, put it back into the box, and return it to Lego because we are too inattentive to build this detailed a project. Stay healthy,
Attila

Comment: I’m on that right now and have rebuilt this 3 times!! Great clarification!! Thank you!

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I was delighted to discover this thread when I googled the exact same problem. I had made the same mistake with the same piece, and just knew it was wrong when it didn't sit flush, but couldn't for the life of me, see the error. Clearly, it's a common problem as this thread has had 938 views! I really appreciate the detailed Q&A. Cheers from Sydney, Australia.